# Difference between MFB bound and ML bound for ISI channels?

Tags: digital-communications, signal-detection, finite-impulse-response

I am considering a straight forward simulation setup in matlab.

I am transmitting a random sequence $\mathbf{x}$ of $\{+1,-1\}$ over a two-tap ISI channel $\mathbf{h}=[h_0 \hspace{2mm} h_1]$. The channel output is the noisy  filtered vector $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{H}\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{n}$.
At receiver, I am implementing ML detector via Viterbi Algorithm to compute $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$.

I want to compare BER vs SNR for my simulation with the **Matched Filtered Bound** and **Maximum Likelihood Bound**. So what is the difference between these two and how can I compute these? 
ML bound uses notion of $d_{min}$ but I don't understand how to compute it for any $\mathbf{h}$.

Can someone guide me here.

Comment: Do you have any references for the maximum likelihood bound?

Comment: Take a look at G. Forney, "Maximum-likelihood sequence estimation of digital sequences in the presence of intersymbol interference," in IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, vol. 18, no. 3, pp. 363-378, May 1972.